# Movendo em uma matriz

Tags: c++, c++20

Eu tô tentando criar um 2048 em c++ e para testar o movimento dos números de um extremo da linha até o outro eu criei esse programa onde um único número dois tenta sair da posição 0 até a posição 3 da primeira linha, porém ele sempre ou executa o loop for muito mais que deveria ou não passa as posições na matriz. Alguém pode me dizer o que eu tô fazendo de errado?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int tabela[4][4]; // nossa matriz

void mover(char tecla){
    int cont, x = 3, y = 3;
    for(cont = 0 ; cont != 15 ; cont++){
        if(cont%4 == 0 and cont != 0){
            x = 0;
            y--;
        }
        if(tabela[x-1][y] == 0 and tabela[x][y] != 0){
            tabela[x][y] = tabela[x-1][y];
            tabela[x][y] = 0;
        }
        x--;
        cout << cont << "\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    int cont,x,y;
    char tecla;
    for(cont = 0 ; cont != 16 ; cont++){ // aqui ele cria a tabela colocando tudo como 0
        if(cont%4 == 0 and cont != 0){
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }else{
            tabela[x][y] = 0;
            x++;
        }
    }
    tabela[0][0] = 2, tabela;
    while(true){
        x = 0 , y = 0;
        for(cont = 0 ; cont != 16 ; cont++){ // aqui ele ficará mostrando a tabela atualizada
            if(cont%4 == 0 and cont != 0){
                x = 0;
                y++;
                cout << "\n";
            }
            cout << "[" << tabela[x][y] << "]";
            x++;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> tecla; // variável usada futuramente. Agora infelizmente é inútil
        mover(tecla);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não é mais simples aninhar dois `for` um dentro do outro não?

Answer (score 0):

No seu código me parece haver alguns problemas na função `mover`. Não sei se esse era seu intuito original, mas o que você está fazendo é **deslocar para a esquerda os elementos da sua matriz que não são zero e estão à direta de um elemento de valor 0**. Por exemplo, a matriz do exemplo da figura abaixo torna-se uma matriz contendo apenas zeros após primeira iteração da função `mover`:

[Último elemento da matriz, com valor 2, torna-se zero após a 1a iteração da função mover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2hnj.png)

Além disso, o verdadeiro problema da função `mover` está na lógica usada para resetar o valor de `x` em conjunto com o seu decremento. Repeti abaixo a função tal qual você a escreveu e adicionei-lhe alguns comentários para que possamos entender o problema.

```cpp
void mover(char tecla){
    int cont, x = 3, y = 3;
    for(cont = 0 ; cont != 15 ; cont++){
        if(cont%4 == 0 and cont != 0){
            // Ao fazer isso, você acessará, na próxima iteração,
            // o valor armazenado em tabela[-1][y], o que naturalmente causará
            // um comportamento indefinido.
            // Para resolver o problema, use x = 3;
            x = 0;
            y--;
        }
        if(tabela[x-1][y] == 0 and tabela[x][y] != 0){
            tabela[x][y] = tabela[x-1][y]; // Essa linha não serve para nada
            tabela[x][y] = 0;
        }
        x--;
        cout << cont << "\n";
    }
}
```

O ponto central aqui está no primeiro `if` dentro do for da função `mover`: nele você atribui 0 ao valor de x, o que prepara o terreno para que, na próxima iteração, o seu segundo `if` acesse o valor armazenado em `tabela[-1][y]`. Um outro detalhe é que a linha `tabela[x][y] = tabela[x-1][y];` não tem efeito alguns, pois logo após você atribui 0 ao valor de `tabela[x][y]`. Assim sendo, para consertar o problema (sem corrigir o efeito da função, que deveria ser de deslocar o 2 na posição [0][0] para a posição [0][3]), você pode utilizar o código a seguir:

```cpp
void mover(char tecla){
    int cont, x = 3, y = 3;
    // Alterei o teste para que o loop vá até cnt == 11
    // para evitar que se acessem índices negativos no segundo if.
    for(cont = 0 ; cont != 12 ; cont++){
        if(cont % 4 == 0 and cont != 0){
            x = 3;
            y--;
        }
        if(tabela[x-1][y] == 0 and tabela[x][y] != 0){
            tabela[x][y] = tabela[x-1][y];
            tabela[x-1][y] = 0;
        }
        x--;
        cout << cont << "\n";
    }
}
```

### Versão mover que desloca para a direita

Como você falou que queria deslocar o número 2 da posição 0 até a posição 3, fiz uma modificação na sua função mover para que se obtenha o efeito desejado.

```cpp
void moverModificada(char tecla){
    int cont, x = 0, y = 0;
    for(cont = 0 ; cont != 12 ; cont++){
        if(cont%3 == 0 and cont != 0){
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
        if(tabela[x+1][y] == 0 and tabela[x][y] != 0){
            tabela[x+1][y] = tabela[x][y];
            tabela[x][y] = 0;
        }
        x++;
        cout << cont << "\n";
    }
}
```

[resultado da função mover modificada, que desloca para a direita](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpyTF.png)

Aqui não entrei na questão de como você decidiu mostra a sua matriz na tela ou no uso da verificação `cnt % 4`, por exemplo, ao invés de se usar dois `for` aninhados, porque você queria apenas saber o que havia de errado com o código. Todavia, o seu código se tornaria mais fácil de entender se você substituísse o único laço `for` com o `if(cont%4 == 0 and cont != 0)` por dois `for` aninhados (um dentro do outro).

Espero que tenha ajudado. Boa continuação!